# Can this be down with sitemap trimming?

Tags: asp.net, sitemap

It seems like this should work but it doesnt.

Im logged in as a Power user and should see 1 report but I actually see 2.

```
<siteMapNode url="Reports" title="Reports"  description="" roles="Administrator, Power">
  <siteMapNode url="default.aspx" title="Default"  description="" roles="Administrator" />
  <siteMapNode url="custom.aspx" title="Custom"  description="" roles="Administrator, Power" />
</siteMapNode>
```

This should work right?

Comment: Any ideas? I think this would be a fairly common thing to setup where different roles can access the same page and some pages certain roles can't access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry if you've already checked this (you don't mention it) but have you enabled trimming in web.config?

`securityTrimmingEnabled="true"`

[ASP.NET Site-Map Security Trimming on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178428.aspx) shows this 'example' web.config

```
<system.web>
<!-- …other configuration settings -->
  <siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
    <providers>
      <add name="XmlSiteMapProvider"
        description="Default SiteMap provider."
        type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider "
        siteMapFile="Web.sitemap"
        securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />
    </providers>
  </siteMap>
</system.web>
```

HTH